# What can I do to ensure fields longer than column width go to the BAD File?

Tags: oracle, external, sql-loader, oracle11gr2

When creating Oracle external tables, how should I phrase the `reject rows` clause to ensure that any field which exceeds its column width rejects and goes in the BADFILE?

This is my current design and I don't want records greater than 20 characters. I do want them to go BADFILE instead. Yet, they still appear when I `select * from foobar`

```
DROP TABLE FOOBAR CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE FOOBAR
(
 FOO_MAX20  VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
 )
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
 (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
 DEFAULT DIRECTORY FOOBAR
 ACCESS PARAMETERS 
   ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
     BADFILE     'foobar_bad_rec.txt'
     DISCARDFILE 'foobar_discard_rec.txt'
     LOGFILE     'foobar_logfile.txt'
     FIELDS
     MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
     REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS 
            (
            FOO_MAX20 POSITION(1:20)
            )
      )
 LOCATION (foobar:'foobar.txt') )
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
PARALLEL ( DEGREE DEFAULT INSTANCES DEFAULT )
NOMONITORING;
```

Here is my external file `foobar.txt`

```
1234567
1234567890123456
126464843750476074218751012345678901234567890
7135009765625
048669433593
7
527
```

Comment: In lieu of screenshots of control file, why not the actual control file text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with the `reject rows` clause, as [it only accepts one form](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#SUTIL1406).

You have a variable-length (delimited) record, but a fixed-length field. Everything after the last position you specify, which is 20 in this case, is seen as filler that you want to ignore. That isn't an error condition; you might have rubbish at the end that isn't relevant to your table. There is nothing that says chars 21-45 in your third record shouldn't be there - just that you aren't interested in them.

It would be nice if you could discard them with the `load when` clause, but you don't seem to be able to compare , say, `(21:21)` to null or an empty string - the former isn't recognised and the latter causes an internal error, which isn't good.

You can make the longer records be sent to the bad file by forcing an SQL error when it tries to put a longer parsed value from the file into the field, by changing:

```
FOO_MAX20 POSITION(1:20)
```

to

```
FOO_MAX20 POSITION(1:21)
```

Values that are up to 20 characters are still loaded:

```
select * from foobar;

FOO_MAX20          
--------------------
1234567              
1234567890123456     
7135009765625        
048669433593         
7                    
527                  

 6 rows selected
```

but for anything longer than 20 characters it'll try to put 21 chars in to the database's 20-char field, which gets this in the log:

```
error processing column FOO_MAX20 in row 3 for datafile /path/to/dir/foobar.txt
ORA-12899: value too large for column FOO_MAX20 (actual: 21, maximum: 20)
```

And the bad file gets that record:

```
126464843750476074218751012345678901234567890
```

Comment: Alex, so you're getting the third record to go into the BADFILE using the code I posted?

Comment: @zundarz - not with the code you posted; with the `POSITION` range changed from `(1:20)` to `(1:21)`.

Comment: In either case,(1:20) or (1:21) shouldn't the third record go to the bad file since its length is 45?

Comment: @zundarz - your records aren't fixed-length though, so as far as the loader is concerned everything after position 20 is just filler that you're not interested in. Your `POSITION(1:20)` is telling it only use those 20 chars, so there is no error condition. I'm forcing an SQL (not file parse) error by trying to use 21 chars, if there are that many.

Answer (score 0):

Have a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on the column to not allow any value exceeding the `LENGTH'.

Comment: This is an external table. I get `ORA-30657: operation not supported on external organized table' when I add a constraint condition`

Comment: I see. Alex nailed it!